# Псевдонимы в Linux

Tags: linux

Знакомлюсь с Линукс. Хочу создать псевдоним рекурсивного копирования с выводом DONE, если все прошло успешно.

```
$ alias cpRI="cp -ri $ $ && echo "DONE""
```

Как сделать, чтобы пользователь на месте знаков доллара мог вводить путь к каталогам?

Comment: Нельзя внутри кавычек использовать такие же. У вас вторая кавычка закрывает первую и слово DONE ни к чему не относится.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Алиасы не предназначены для таких действий. Но это можно сделать с помощью объявления функции:

```
function cpRI { cp -ri "$1" "$2" && echo "DONE"; }
```

Данный код можно разместить в файле `~/.bash_aliases`, а "подключить" в bash путем добавления в `~/.bashrc` следующего:

```
if [ -f ~/.bash_aliases ]; then
    . ~/.bash_aliases
fi
```

**Либо**:

```
 alias cpri="cp -ri"
```

Но тогда использовать так:

```
 cpri srcFolder destFolder && echo DONE
```

PS.

Linux-way: если команда выполнилась успешно - она ничего не выводит. Вы пытаетесь повторить dos-way, сообщая "Все хорошо". На этот случай намного лучше:

- результат выполнения команды можно получить через `$?` - просто напечатайте и увидите код ошибки или ноль
- это `$?` можно использовать для подсветки приглашения командной строки (красить красным) - легко ищется по `bash prompt color error`
- некоторые команды имеют многословный режим "verbose" - выводится все дополнительная информация

Comment: Про `$?` не знал. Афигенная штука, спасибо.

Comment: @donRumata, о сколько нам открытий чудных готовит... $ Иногда полезно проходить интервью в гугол, там на админские должности иногда спрашивают, «а расскажите, какие специальные переменные в shell вы знаете?» Ответ по сути — берёшь ASCII таблицу, выкидываешь буквы, цифры и непечатные символы — и вперёд!